# Add Property to my NPM Module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, typescript

This might be answered, but damn if I can find it . I am creating a module, and its working, the issue is I want to assign a property to another property on my module.

so in angular 2 (with ng-module) I have created a simple panel

```
<simple-panel name="MyPanel"></simple-panel>
```

I have it working great, the issue is I want to assign a property to the name Property now and I have no idea what is the best way to do this.

so I would like to return {{MyPanel.thisProperty}} for use on the page where I am calling the tag.

here is a sample of what I am doing, stripped down for this question

here is my simple-panel.ts

---

```
    import {Component,NgModule,ModuleWithProviders, Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';


    /**
 * Content of the edit panel.
 */

@Directive({
  selector: 'simple-panel-edit-panel-content'
})
export class SimplePanelEditPanelContent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-panel',
  templateUrl: 'simple-panel.html',
  styleUrls: ['simple-panel.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})


export class SimplePanel{
    private _name: string;
    private _announceedit: boolean = false;
    private _buttonname: string = 'edit';

    /** This sets the Name as a variable that can be used. */
    @Input()
    get name(): string { return this._name; }
    set name(value) { this._name = value; }

 /**Sets the Edit Announcement */
    @Input()
    get editannounce(): boolean { return this._announceedit; }
    set editannounce(value: boolean) {
      if (!value) {
      this._announceedit = true;
      this._buttonname = 'search';
    }else{
      this._announceedit = false;
      this._buttonname = 'edit';
    }
     }


}

@NgModule({
  exports: [SimplePanel,SimplePanelEditPanelContent],
  declarations: [SimplePanel,SimplePanelEditPanelContent],
})
export class SimplePanelComponent {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SimplePanelComponent,
      providers: []
    };
  }
}
```

---

here is the simple-panel.html

```
<md-card>
      <md-card-title-group>
            <button md-raised-button (click)="editannounce=editannounce;"><md-icon>{{ _buttonname }}</md-icon></button>
      </md-card-title-group>
      <md-card-content>
         <ng-content select="simple-panel-edit-panel-content"></ng-content>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions>
        <button md-raised-button (click)="editannounce = editannounce"><md-icon>save</md-icon> SAVE</button>
      </md-card-actions>
  </md-card>
```

---

when someone uses the module, a panel is created with a button 
when someone clicks the button I can access the variable within the template above, but what I want to do is actually access  a variable that is used on the page itself where they call the module to use. it would be nice to have it named MyPanel.announceedit or MyPanel.editable as an example, but the main thing is that a variable is created, and watched, when it changes it passes it back up to where the module is bieng used and allows  user the ability to access it within the content area, so if they added an input and wanted to see if the button was clicked to set the readOnly attribute they could. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you write it like

```
<simple-panel [name]="MyPanel"></simple-panel>
```

in the component that includes this html, you can access/set MyPanel with a simple `this.MyPanel`.

And in your `SimplePanel` component

```
@Input() name;
...
this.name = "something";
```

is again all you need to set and get that field.

Comment: I can do that, the issue is simply this , in the simple-panel.html I have a button, when someone clicks that button I want to access a property of the simple-panel that I can pass back so the content of the panel (which is set by the user) can access it. I can do that easily within the simple-panel.html template , but I am not sure how to pass it up to the view page outside the module.

So this would be a variable that the user can access within there own page, above the module template, I would like to access it via some branding ie name of the simple-panel , that the users sets.

Comment: @LiamBayly oh do you mean like template variables? check this doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars%23template-reference-variables